# Link from one place to another in Microsoft WORD document

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a document.

I must edit it.

Is there a way for me to create some sort of software link between point A and point B of this Word.DOC file, so that I can test and check and make sure that I didn't screw up some logistics stuff that is in it ?

e.g., there are some numbered things that must be renumbered.

By the way, if this is explained in the MS-Word *help* system, please tell me how to click to find it. I couldn't figure out how to ask the question.

Comment: It is very unclear exactly what you are asking. Maybe you could take some nice screenshots to help show people what you are talking about.

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a hyperlink. Try searching for hyperlink in Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for are bookmarks: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/add-or-delete-bookmarks-HP001226532.aspx

The instructions may be different in different versions of Word.

Comment: Perfect, excellent answer, and I thank you for your brains. This is exactly and precisely what I needed to know.